# GIT: how to change the actual username when pushing changes

Tags: git, ssh

i'm trying to fetch changes using git gui, the problem is that i'm getting a dialog window asking for a password:

```
OpenSSH
Administrator@IP-ADDRESS's password:
```

as you can see the username is Administrator which is the account name of my Win7 machine.
how would i change that username?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
```

If you only want it for that specific project, leave off the `--global`.

If you need to change the email as well, similarly:

```
git config --global user.email "myname@email.com"
```

Comment: thanks, i did that but when fetching, it's still showing the password dialog with Administrator@... :/ .. when entering git config user.name i'm getting the desired (new) username but when pulling there's still administrator

Comment: That sounds like the login/password to your `git` server. If you have admin privileges to the `git` server, then you can change your credentials or create a normal user on that server.

Comment: i found a temp solution: i added a new account on my machine which is identical to my git username, then it worked. unfortunately i'm not having full access to my desktop, app settings and such .. :/